# Springdoc OpenAPI v2.1.0 in Spring Boot v.3.0.3 project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, openapi

When using the latest springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui v.2.1.0 in Spring Boot v.3.0.3 version build in JDK v17 the default swagger-ui/index.html gets loaded without content. The HTML site at `localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` loads header, scripts but does not pupulate the targe swagger-ui div with any content. The api-docs throug `http://localhost:8080/api-docs` get me a HTTP Error 401.

I have worked on that issue quite a while now downgrading to older springdoc version or even trying to implement the older Swagger2. The Maven project works and I get access to the endpoint but won't see any web content. I only see this html from the server:

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div> <!-- Missing content here -->
    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-initializer.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone spot the issue? This project POM, application.properties, controller, model and cofiguration and main class look as follows: Thank you very much for having a look!

**Project POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>preproduction-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SampleApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Security and Authentication -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Persistance -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kotlin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Templating -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DTO Mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Api Docu -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Project recource: application.properties**

```
############# Springdoc OpenAPI Config ###########
#springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
#paths-to-match =/api/**
#springdoc.enable-native-support=true
#springdoc.show-actuator=true
#springdoc.use-management-port=true
# This property enables the openapi and swagger-ui endpoints to be exposed beneath the actuator base path.
#management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=openapi, swagger-ui
#management.server.port=9090
```

**Project configuration: OpenAPI Configuration**

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springdoc.core.properties.SpringDocConfigProperties;
import org.springdoc.core.properties.SwaggerUiConfigParameters;
import org.springdoc.core.properties.SwaggerUiConfigProperties;
import org.springdoc.core.providers.SpringWebProvider;
import org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI expenseAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Demo API")
                        .description("Demo application")
                        .version("v0.0.1")
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("Wiki Documentation")
                        .url(""));
    }
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc swaggerWelcome(SwaggerUiConfigProperties swaggerUiConfig, SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties, SwaggerUiConfigParameters swaggerUiConfigParameters, SpringWebProvider springWebProvider) {
        return new SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc(swaggerUiConfig, springDocConfigProperties, swaggerUiConfigParameters, springWebProvider);
    }
}
```

**Project configuration: Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    RSAPublicKey publicKey;

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/subreddit")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                                "/configuration/ui",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/configuration/security",
                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                "/swagger-ui/index.html",
                                "/webjars/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                ).build();
    }
}
```

**Project configuration: WebMvc Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(3600L)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

**Sample Controller: 'User' Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody PostRequest postRequest ) {
        userService.save(postRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostResponse>> getAllUsers() {
        return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(postService.getAllUsers());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostResponse> getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(postService.getUser(id));
    }
}
```

**Sample Model: 'User' Model**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Instant created;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

**Sample Repo: 'User' Repo**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
}
```

**Spring Boot Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@Import(OpenAPIConfiguration.class)
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(com.company.SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Server Start log**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-07-05T15:20:45.480+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] c.p.t.s.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication using Java 20.0.1 with PID 15944 (C:\Users\xxxxx\IdeaProjects\spring-reddit-clone2\target\classes started by xxxxx in C:\Users\xxxxx\IdeaProjects\spring-reddit-clone2)
2023-07-05T15:20:45.484+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] c.p.t.s.DemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-05T15:20:46.534+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-05T15:20:46.634+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 88 ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-05T15:20:47.468+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-05T15:20:47.489+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-05T15:20:47.489+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-07-05T15:20:47.603+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-05T15:20:47.604+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2056 ms
2023-07-05T15:20:47.785+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-05T15:20:47.838+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-07-05T15:20:48.153+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-05T15:20:48.313+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3a861417
2023-07-05T15:20:48.315+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-05T15:20:48.366+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

... omitting Hibernate calls

2023-07-05T15:20:50.268+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-05T15:20:50.280+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-05T15:20:51.157+02:00  WARN 15944 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-05T15:20:51.847+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1d77d9c6, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2c5b4b91, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@73502d5e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@69f55ea, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@51eeae0a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@524b1e41, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@160d68b8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@213bd66a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@244c0fbe, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@76c2d002, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7866ffa, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@69ee0861, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@43d2c8e3]
2023-07-05T15:20:52.261+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-05T15:20:52.271+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] c.p.t.s.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 7.224 seconds (process running for 7.656)
2023-07-05T15:21:24.621+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-05T15:21:24.622+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-05T15:21:24.623+02:00  INFO 15944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

**What I tried to identify the root causing that issue:**

- downgrade Springdoc OpenAPI to older version (including SpringFox Swagger2)
- altering configuration for WebMVC, Security and OpenApi
- trying differenct ways to access Swagger endpoint and URL
- Switching to older JDKs
- Turn off Microsoft Defender
- Try the whole setup on a different machine and in older IntelliJ versions

Comment: I think few logs from when the server start would be useful, if you have some.

Comment: I tried some more approaches and still am stuck with that same OpenApi issue. Included the server start log to my original problem description.

Comment: One of the funniest issue that happened once to me with openapi, was my fault : I didn't provide the executable Spring Services classes in the fat jar executed :-). But check this intermediate step, if you can : does openapi generates a json file, during a maven step? Typically a `openapi.json` file. If that file is empty, the problem is in the generation of the service, if it is full of "good things" but nothing displays on swagger web page, it's a deployment issue. For example, the `openapi.json` that isn't at the place swagger-ui can find it. I don't remember if it needs it, itself.

Comment: After trying several approaches I came to the conclusion that the latest OpenAPI implementation by SpringDoc v.2.1.0 istincompatible with the recent Spring Boot v.3.0.3.